# Cypress scroll on test failure

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, e2e-testing

Im trying to find out if it's possible to make a viewport scroll to bottom of the page when the tests fails so I can see what is the state of the page on failure (video record) because it's not shown in full during recording.
Other thing would be possible the screenshot but that also would need to be taken on the whole page not just the available viewport height not sure how to setup this.

I've tried this but doesn't seem to work.

```
Cypress.Screenshot.defaults({
  capture: 'fullPage',
})
```

Anyway scroll of the page to the bottom so its recorder in the video on failure would be the best option.

Any ideas if this is possible? How to do it?